# Check if null for part of session variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

If I have 30 session variables and I want to do an if statement to only 10 of them.

```
if (empty($_SESSION['XYZ'])) {
   $_SESSION['XYZ'] = 0;
}
```

what should I do? Do I call an if statement after every session variables that i needed for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider putting the names of the keys  in an array and then looping through with foreach.

```
$keys = array('x','y','z');
foreach ($keys as $key)
{
    if (empty($_SESSION[$key])
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

An advantage is you can quickly add or remove keys to check.

Answer (score 1):

```
$vars = array('XYZ','ABC','DEF');

foreach($vars as $i){
  if(empty($_SESSION[$i])) $_SESSION[$i] = 0;
}
```

[edit]
I like how we have the same answer 4 times now, and counting!

Answer (score 0):

If they are in series, that is, from 0 to 29 then you can use a loop to traverse them!

Answer (score 0):

Something like so?

```
$keys = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could list the keys you want to zero-out in an array and set them as follows:

```
$keys = array('XYZ','FOO','BAR');

foreach ($keys as $key) {
  if (empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = 0;
  }
}
```